# How to use sudo from within Windows GUI clients bypassing tty

Tags: windows, ssh, filezilla, winscp, tty

I need to copy files via ssh but I am getting permission denied.

How can I log as a root by windows clients such us FileZilla/WinSCP?

I try execute command:

sudo su, but I am getting error: You must have tty to run sudo.

I try to resolve this error but without luck.

Comment: A little trick is you can use /tmp as a temporary place and then move the files from it, beware of security and space limitations though.

Comment: For WinSCP, see [How to change user in winSCP?](http://superuser.com/questions/647919/how-to-change-user-in-winscp)

Answer (score 3):

What the basic problem here is that there is a protection again non-human input. TTY ensures that the action is performed from keyboard actions, and not from another program. Now there is a way around this.

If you have access to the sodeors file you can deal with this. It is not really recommended but here goes, this is really a way that works.

You open the file `/etc/sudoers` and you find the following line:

```
Defaults:myusername    !requiretty
```

This tells the the system that the user `myusername` can perform non-keyboard actions. Now you can work with all your files using the sudo command.

Best is to try to avoid this.

Comment: Once you setup the `requiretty` flag as this answer explains, follow this guide to setup WinSCP to use `sudo`: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with Amazon Web Services and WinSCP the adjusting the sudoers keyboard input status does not work because WinSCP continues to throw a SSH command that AWS does not understand and will give a bash error.

I was having the same problem and solved it using the steps in this tutorial:

> [How to Login in as SSH root user from WinSCP to AWS](http://cvlive.blogspot.de/2014/03/how-to-login-in-as-ssh-root-user-from.html)
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: You could post the summary without screenshots. Posting just a link is not a good practice.

Comment: Turning off *keyboard-interactive* authentication is irrelevant, imho. It has nothing to do with TTY. And it affects SSH authentication phase only. `sudo`'s turn is only after SSH authentication phase. Read about [keyboard-interactive authentication](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_authenticate#keyboard_interactive).

Comment: i'm facing the same problem and thank god I found something here :) One question, what are the command that this will need to allow from sudo config?

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider to log in as your root user on the server rather than using `su` or `sudo`, this could be done by username or password or via a key file. However, the server should allow you to do this; if not, there is not much that you can do to remotely gain root acces...

Comment: I logged in by key/username which I get from my boss, but it gives me nothing at all, I can't copy files at all

Answer (score 1):

With WinSCP, check the "Avanced Options" box.
In the Environnement>SFTP section, select the "sudo su -c /bin/sftp-server" option.

Indeed, your SSH server has to be configured to allow you lauchning such command.

Comment: For more details, see http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about a problem with tty.