# How to change user in WinSCP?

Tags: linux, unix, putty, sudo, winscp

I'm using WinSCP to access Unix computers. How can I change user after I have logged into a Unix server using WinSCP?

E.g. I have personal account in Unix computer A. I can log into this computer using PuTTY and then change user to root user

```
$sudo /usr/bin/su - rootuser
```

How can I do the same thing using WinSCP? I don't know the password for `rootuser`.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to assume you can already sudo to the user in question ...
... in WinSCP setup for a new site:

1. New Site
2. Session: File protocol: SCP
3. Session: host name: my-host-name
4. Session: user name: MY-user-name
5. CLICK Advanced... BUTTON
6. Advanced: *left-hand-navigator* select SCP/Shell
7. Advanced:Shell: *MAGIC-HAPPENS-HERE*  The "pick list" for Shell has "Default" selected. You will enter TEXT here...

   /usr/bin/sudo -u TARGET-user-name -i

(above command varies by unix distro)

8. *NO-OTHER-CHANGES* to the default settings, just select OK to close the Advanced window and save your changes.

..... this *should* be all you need!

Answer (score 6):

There is a FAQ for this question on WinSCP site:
[How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

You need to specify the `sudo` command in WinSCP session settings, as a custom shell (if you are using SCP) or use the `sudo` in a custom SFTP server startup command (if you are using SFTP).

Though there are some limitations, notably that you need to configure the `sudo` not to require a password.

See the link for details.

Answer (score 0):

For SCP, What works for me, using WinSCP to connect to Ubuntu system as rootuser:

Put this as shell

```
sudo -su rootuser
```

[image]