# How to do sesu login in WINSCP?

Tags: permissions, winscp

Hi I use putty and can do a sesu login with required password. but I use different user(A1) to connect to remote solaris server and then use the sesu option with another user(A2) to get the permissions.
but when I use winscp with A1 I do get very limited permission again there is owner issues as some files are generated and some are transferred.

How can I change to user A2 with sesu access?

**Note :** I have checked [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/647919/how-to-change-user-in-winscp) but I could not figure out exactly how to use sesu(I have also tried the solutions given by Martin Prikryl but they are not working). I am also aware of [WINSCP page](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su) I tried remote execution commands also but I could not provide the password as we can not give user input through winscp terminal.

Comment: Not sure how `sesu` works. But as with `sudo`, if you cannot or do not want to configure it not to require a password, you cannot make it working with WinSCP.

Comment: Unfortunately the configuration part is not under our control hence we have to use the password. but I am surprised that Winscp does not provide solution to this problem as apart from this its a robust application.

Comment: Because it's just not possible. The `sudo` and similar tools are (rightly) built specifically **not to allow** you to automate the privileges escalation for security reasons. So WinSCP cannot automate it for you.

Comment: Yes definitely I understand the security issues but if a user is genuinely need the access and he has the authorization(password) then winscp can at least provide a way or ask the password when login or transferring the files with sesu access.

Comment: No it cannot, because the `sudo` and similar tools generally require TTY for the password prompt, what is not compatible with the SFTP protocol.