# Using WinSCP (File Protocol SCP) with a server that requires "dzdo su -" for sudo

Tags: scp, winscp

**TOPIC:** Using WinSCP (File Protocol SCP) with a server that requires `dzdo su -` for `sudo`

We have a few Linux Servers that require the logged in user to issue the following command to emulate the root user: `dzdo su -`

I have not found the right combination of settings to allow WinSCP to connect with our Server using the `dzdo su -` option.

I have found several articles with different options to no avail. Any recommendations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you clarify how/why this dzdo command needs to be run as part of an scp transfer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change user in WinSCP?](https://superuser.com/questions/647919/how-to-change-user-in-winscp)